# Run docker-compose from Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have `Jenkins` running inside a `Docker` container with `docker.sock` mounted. Can I call `docker-compose` from this container to run a service on host machine? I tried executing installation script from within a container, but it keeps saying

> "no such file or directory".

```
docker exec jenkins curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

docker exec jenkins chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: What docker image are you using for that jenkins container? It should have docker-compose installed in it

Comment: I use the Blue Ocean latest

Comment: Could you post the jenkinsfile you use for build?

Answer (score 0):

It is achievable but tricky to get it right.

You need to mount with a *docker volume* the path the docker-compose.yml file is in on your docker host, to the exact same location in the container.

So if the docker-compose.yml file location is `/home/leonid/workspace/project1/docker-compose.yml` on the docker host, you need to add the volume `-v /home/leonid/workspace/project1/:/home/leonid/workspace/project1/` for the jenkins container.

Then, in your Jenkins job:

```sh
cd /home/leonid/workspace/project1/
docker-compose up -d
```

**Why is that?**

Keep in mind that docker-compose gives instructions to the docker engine. The docker engine runs on the docker host (and not in the Jenkins container). So any path given by docker-compose to the docker engine must exist on the docker host.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough, getting the `docker-compose.yml` isn't the problem since it's fetched from git, the problem is that actual `docker-compose` binary doesn't exist in the container and I'm not sure how to make it work from within

Comment: So, you are not sure how to install it?

Comment: I guess so, my attempt to install it with `docker exec` didn't bring any success

Answer (score 0):

Create your own dockerfile that is based on image you use for build (probably docker:latest)

Then, in RUN line put downloading the docker-compose and setting it as executable.

Spin up jenkins agent to build from your image instead default one.

you need to install docker-compose on that build container, not on jenkins master.

For builds in gitlab-ci I had a special build container that based on docker image with compose installed additionally. I think this is your case - you are using jenkins to spin a container based on docker:latest which by default does not have docker-compose. You need to either create own image that is from docker:latest, install compose or use some image from docekrhub that is done like this.

Also, you could try to install compose as part of your build. Just download it to some local dir and use it from there.

Comment: wouldn't it be the same as `docker exec`?

Comment: Is Jenkins creating new container for each build run or building on the master image? If so, you will not have time to install with docker exec as container lives only during build.

Answer (score 0):

The "Install as a container" section in the docs worked for me: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

```
sudo curl -L --fail https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/run.sh -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```